# Scrolling the UITableView to the selected section header

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

How to increase the height of the table so that the selected table header is on top?

Comment: You might use the `tableFooterView` with the correct height, or play with its `contentSize` or `contentInset` might do the trick.

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: yourSectionIndex)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}

Comment: @Larme I'm trying to add a footer by clicking on a tab, but nothing comes out ...

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is `know the number of section` you want to move on.
If your section is composed of "A", "B", "C", the section number of "C" is 2.

```swift
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animation: true)
```

You can use this code when you click on the tab.